# Show content type form to block

Tags: blocks

I've created one content type named Newsletter. And I want to display that content type form to block. I've tried with this code but failure. Your suggestions will be appreciated.

```
$my_module_form = drupal_get_form('blog-node-form');
$my_module_form = drupal_render($my_module_form);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use [Advance form block](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb) which supports ajax submission and multiple form with same content type.

**FORM BLOCK:**

1. **Create** any number of blocks with a particular **node edit form**.
2. **Create** any number of blocks with a particular **node add form** of a content type.
3. **Create** as **many blocks** as you like of **each kind**.
4. From the content type **choose which fields to display on a per block basis**.However required fields will be automatically displayed.
5. All forms will be **saved through ajax**. So **multiple node forms** can be independently placed on a single page and **worked with simultaneously**.

Answer (score 1):

Using contrib modules will certainly help for this. There are at least two I can think of:

- Form Block (https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock)
- Advanced From Block (https://www.drupal.org/project/afb)

To answer your question, however, you need to instantiate a new (or existing) node object to set as your `form_state` (Assuming the machine readable name of your content type is "newsletter").

```
global $user;  
$node = (object) array('uid' => $user->uid, 'name' => (isset($user->name) ? $user->name : ''), 'type' => 'newsletter', 'language' => LANGUAGE_NONE);
$form_state['build_info']['args'] = array($node);
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$form = drupal_build_form('newsletter_node_form', $form_state);
```

If you want the form to edit an existing node, the you can replace the `$node = (object)` part with a `node_load([nid])` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Form Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/formblock) module. It allows to embed a contact/registration/node form as block.

> Enables the presentation of user registration, site wide contact, or
>   node creation forms in blocks. This is particularly useful for
>   including forms on panels.